# Swift URLSession tasks download order

Tags: ios, background, urlsession

I need to download multiple files sequentially. I'd also like to have the possibility, in the future, to put a time interval between each download, to reduce the server load (I'm downloading tiles from OpenStreetMap). This download must be able to run in the background.

I'm currently doing this:

```
let config:URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:"offline-map-download");
config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true;
config.isDiscretionary = true;

let queue:OperationQueue = OperationQueue();
queue.name = "download";
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

let session = URLSession(configuration:config, delegate:self, delegateQueue:queue);

for i in 0 ..< 10 {

    let url:URL = URL(string:"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/7/63/\(i).png")!;

    print("add \(url) to queue");

    session.dataTask(with:url).resume();
}
```

And here is my delegate's didCompleteWithError method:

```
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {

    print("received \(task.currentRequest!.url!)");
}
```

I'd expect the "received" logs to be printed in the same order as the "add to queue" logs. That's not the case. Is it normal?

More generally, am I on the right path to have a background download (equivalent to an Android service)? For now I don't have a real device and I'm using the simulator. Is my app going in background when I press the home button (asking this because even if I use the URLSessionConfiguration.default config, when I press home, my download continues)?

Comment: Subclass `Operation` class. Handle the download there. Define a OperationQueue similar to `queue` in the above code. This way the operations which are added to this queue are executed in serial way i.e in FIFO order.

Comment: Subclass Operation, or OperationQueue ? If Operation, how should I use it then?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift. Use this tutorial to see how you can implement. Note it is using old swift syntax.

Comment: OK I see. But why is the order respected when adding to the queue manually, and not when using session.dataTask? Also, do you have an answer for the background questions?

Comment: You can forget about `;` in swift code. The `OperationQueue` controls how the operations are executed. Here the session.dataTask is executed in asynchronously fashin. Also you can check this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started, for background sessions.

Comment: Yep I already saw this tutorial, I'll do it entirely tomorrow. I'll came back with an answer or more questions ^^. For the ; , yes I know, but habits die hard...